# How to list and add ip as target to target group using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-elb

In the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.register_targets) I see how to add a target. I need to check if particular IP is already on the list of targets. There's no instance id, just IP. How can I do that (using boto3)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious and against usual naming, but there is such a function: `describe_target_health(...)` will provide you with the list of all targets if you omit the `Targets` parameter.